How to allow only my local network access to my server (on the same network) via domain?
I have a web server at home already configured and accessible to the public
From any device on my local network I can connect to my server using the server's local IP (192.168.1.7)
When I enable port forwarding from any IP address (0.0.0.0)

I can access my web server from my public IP and my domain but what I want is to limit IP access
What I have tried:

Connect a device on my local network to a VPN and configure port forwarding from that IP, now my server only has access from that IP but I can't connect all my devices to the same VPN

Configure port forwarding from my device's local IP (192.168.1.3), now my server only has access from that device but the request doesn't carry the public IP and when I configure more than one device it is only possible to access from one

Configure port forwarding from the router's IP (192.168.1.1) It doesn't work either

Configure port forwarding from my public IP doesn't work either


What I need is to block all incoming traffic except for my local network devices or, failing that, my public IP.
Now the question is, why?
I need to access my web server with my real domain and in HTTPS and for the request to have the remote address, in this case my public IP
Is it possible to do this or is there another way to do it?
Update:



In the left graph it represents a client connected to a VPN when I make the request to the server using domain names, on my web server the request arrives with the IP of the VPN (34.78.202.31 which is a valid public IP)
In the other graph it represents the same client without the VPN when I make the request to the server using domain names, on my web server the request arrives with the IP of the router or the gateway (192.168.1.1 which is not a valid public IP)

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I think you're confused about how IP addresses and domain names work, but it's hard to be sure from what you've written. All IP connections are made by IP address; if you use a domain name, that gets translated into an IP address, and then the actual connection is made using that IP address.

@GordonDavisson What I exactly want to do is to access my web server from my local network devices using domain names and in the request that reaches my server it has a valid public IP address, I updated the question with an image with something of what I more or less think

This sounds like a DNS issue. What does your local DNS server have regarding this domain name and IP?

I don't understand your question

We don't know much about any of the pieces of the puzzle. Maybe use split DNS to route the domain name to the box. Why do you need the public IP address?
